# Permutation/Combination in Python

Tags: python

I am learning Python recently and know that there are usually some good libraries/functions existed already that we don't need to write our own.  I think the problem I am facing is a permutation/combination problem which can be easily solved in Python with **itertools**, but not exactly sure how.

The problem is... I want to order a combo meal in a burger place with exactly the price I want to pay.  The combo consists of 1 burger (opt1) and 1 side+drink (opt2), optionally with 1 more side (opt3) and option for special drink upgrade.

Sample Dataset: (ID, price, description)

```
opt1 = [(1,24,'Beef'),(2,26,'Cheese'),(3,29,'Veggie'),(4,24,'Chicken'),(5,25,'Bacon')]
opt2 = [('A',18,'S Fries'),('B',21,'L Fries'),('C',19,'Nuggets'),('D',22,'Pudding')]
opt3 = [('A',14,'S Fries'),('B',17,'L Fries'),('C',13,'Nuggets'),('D',16,'Pudding'),('-',0,'-')]
opt4 = [('Z',3,'Special Drink'),('-',0,'-')]
```

Say if I am targeting to order a combo of price 58, I can do:

```
def find_combo(target_price):
    for x in opt1:
        for y in opt2:
            for z in opt3:
                for w in opt4:
                    if x[1] + y[1] + z[1] + w[1] == target_price:
                        print "{}:{} {}:{} {}:{} {}:{}".format(x[0],x[2],y[0],y[2],z[0],z[2],w[0],w[2])

find_combo(58)
```

The above works fine, giving me the possible combo options.

```
1:Beef A:S Fries C:Nuggets Z:Special Drink
1:Beef A:S Fries D:Pudding -:-
1:Beef B:L Fries C:Nuggets -:-
4:Chicken A:S Fries C:Nuggets Z:Special Drink
4:Chicken A:S Fries D:Pudding -:-
4:Chicken B:L Fries C:Nuggets -:-
5:Bacon C:Nuggets A:S Fries -:-
```

Here is the question, I have a feeling that the 4 for loops are not necessary with smarter use of Python. So how can this be computed more intelligently?

Comment: Could you post the output of your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to explicitly explore the entire search space... a greedy algorithm wont work

```
def price(*opts):
    return sum(o[1] for o in opts)

exact_matches = [combo for combo in itertools.product(opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4) if price(*combo) == target]
cheaper_matches = [combo for combo in itertools.product(opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4) if price(*combo) < target]
```

this is essentially the same as the four loops above just using a python builtin... under the hood its still just loops